# How to running Python script in virtual machine but read and save on computer local csv file

Tags: python, virtual-machine

I have a Python script deployed and running in azure virtual machine, however in the script, I have to read a local CSV file for further processing, that leads a failure, server came back with notice that: "file does not exist "

May I ask how can I running Python script in VM but read and save on my computer local file ?

If not possible, may I ask how to overcome this problem with cloud storage, particularly with Azure?

Comment: You can either mount a drive into your VM or use a cloud storage service.  Are you trying to do this on a VM running on your local machine or remotely?

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston, Hi Taylor, I am able to do this now: 1st I upload csv file to Azure storage , second i  use Azure Machine Learning workbench's data importing from Azure Storage Blob to get the file to my workbench,3, i use workbench's generate data access code file, finally i am able to to retrieve CSV file from my workbench local enviornment, and use it in my python script. I have the following question: how can i directly read azure blob from cloud to my python script without save to local first, 2, how can i update a azure blob in the cloud without local saving copy.. thank you

Comment: @halfer Hi Halfer, noted,  it will be wonderful for me to meet female soft engineers, i have nothing against them , i was  trying to be polite to anyone reading my post , maybe next time i will try: dear boys and girls, but in that way, i am afriad the some age groups will feel excluded, the most safe way will be ladies and gentalmen , but that sounds weired in our community, its really difficult world to live with to this day from this perspective, lol

Comment: @Pepin: we ask that all salutations and greetings are removed anyway. We also trim thanks, advance thanks, regards, hope-you-can-help and all manner of other chatty material. So, easy solution - don't add it at all `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could possible map the directory to the vm as a network resource?

Comment: Hi Brent, two follow up questions: how can i upload file to VM, and how can i get the network directory ? thank you.

Comment: What kind of vm is it? Linux or windows?

Comment: sorry , i dont know that much, its a linux from azure virtual machine